# Practically unfork process

Tags: process, background-process, debugging, fork, clone

I have an executable binary (no source) that clone()s.
It doesn't print anything and I think the child is trying to, which I'd like it to do.
It always returns successfully even when the child actually failed. 
I'd like the child's return code.
The prompt also returns instantly,
but I'd like something that runs in the foreground;
either by magically unforking it or waiting for the child to terminate.

What can I do? Linux only is ok.

I tried a script like this to at least get output and stay in the foreground:

```
thecmd &
daemon="$(pgrep -P $!)"
cat "/proc/$daemon/fd/2" >&2
```

But the child can fail before I get it and there's no output.

Me trying to get daemon and the stdouts:

```
cmd &
daemon="$(pgrep -P $!)"
echo "daemon: $daemon"

echo "parent's stdout:"
readlink -f "/proc/$!/fd/1"
echo "child's stdout:"
readlink -f "/proc/$daemon/fd/1"
```

prints:

```
daemon:
parent's stdout:
child's stdout:
```

Here is `strace -f` output where the child fails (why no stderr?):

```
23266 execve("/usr/local/sbin/tobiiusbserviced", ["/usr/local/sbin/tobiiusbserviced"], 0x7ffc21846b08 /* 17 vars */) = 0
23266 brk(NULL)                         = 0x2368000
23266 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/haswell/x86_64/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/haswell/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/haswell", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/x86_64/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/tls", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/haswell/x86_64/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/haswell/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/haswell", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/x86_64/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 stat("/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/x86_64", 0x7ffdbcb20d80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libtobii_osal.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23266 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@6\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
23266 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=54270, ...}) = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa9213b8000
23266 mmap(NULL, 2141088, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa9211ad000
23266 mprotect(0x7fa9211b7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
23266 mmap(0x7fa9213b6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x7fa9213b6000
23266 close(3)                          = 0
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libtobii_libc.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23266 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
23266 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56335, ...}) = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 2161696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa920f9d000
23266 mprotect(0x7fa920fa8000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
23266 mmap(0x7fa9211a7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7fa9211a7000
23266 mmap(0x7fa9211a9000, 15392, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa9211a9000
23266 close(3)                          = 0
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23266 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=81564, ...}) = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 81564, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa920f89000
23266 close(3)                          = 0
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libudev.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23266 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200Y\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
23266 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=158016, ...}) = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 162056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa920f61000
23266 mprotect(0x7fa920f66000, 135168, PROT_NONE) = 0
23266 mmap(0x7fa920f66000, 94208, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7fa920f66000
23266 mmap(0x7fa920f7d000, 36864, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x7fa920f7d000
23266 mmap(0x7fa920f87000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fa920f87000
23266 close(3)                          = 0
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23266 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\177\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
23266 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=12976264, ...}) = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 1856160, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa920d9b000
23266 mmap(0x7fa920dc1000, 1351680, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7fa920dc1000
23266 mmap(0x7fa920f0b000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x170000) = 0x7fa920f0b000
23266 mmap(0x7fa920f57000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bb000) = 0x7fa920f57000
23266 mmap(0x7fa920f5d000, 12960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa920f5d000
23266 close(3)                          = 0
23266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libtobii_usb.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
23266 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\30\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
23266 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=33286, ...}) = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 2122072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa920b94000
23266 mprotect(0x7fa920b9a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
23266 mmap(0x7fa920d99000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5000) = 0x7fa920d99000
23266 close(3)                          = 0
23266 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa920b92000
23266 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa920b93040) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x7fa920f57000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x7fa920d99000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x7fa920f87000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x7fa9213b6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x7fa9211a7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x604000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 mprotect(0x7fa9213e4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
23266 munmap(0x7fa920f89000, 81564)     = 0
23266 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fa920b93310) = 23267
23266 exit_group(0 <unfinished ...>
23267 umask(000 <unfinished ...>
23266 <... exit_group resumed>)         = ?
23267 <... umask resumed>)              = 022
23267 setsid( <unfinished ...>
23266 +++ exited with 0 +++
23267 <... setsid resumed>)             = 23267
23267 brk(NULL)                         = 0x2368000
23267 brk(0x2389000)                    = 0x2389000
23267 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/tobiiusb/tobiiusbservice.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
23267 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
23267 write(3, "23267", 5)              = 5
23267 close(3)                          = 0
23267 rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x4023e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fa920dd8000}, NULL, 8) = 0
23267 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {sa_handler=0x402c70, sa_mask=[USR1], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fa920dd8000}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
23267 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {sa_handler=0x402d30, sa_mask=[USR2], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fa920dd8000}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
23267 chdir("/")                        = 0
23267 close(0)                          = 0
23267 close(1)                          = 0
23267 close(2)                          = 0
23267 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/udev/udev.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 0
23267 fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=49, ...}) = 0
23267 read(0, "# see udev.conf(5) for details\n\n"..., 4096) = 49
23267 read(0, "", 4096)                 = 0
23267 close(0)                          = 0
23267 access("/run/udev/control", F_OK) = 0
23267 socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT) = 0
23267 setsockopt(0, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, {len=10, filter=0x7ffdbcb20a20}, 16) = 0
23267 bind(0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=0x000002}, 12) = 0
23267 getsockname(0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=23267, nl_groups=0x000002}, [12]) = 0
23267 setsockopt(0, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0
23267 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 1
23267 read(1, "0-3\n", 8192)            = 4
23267 close(1)                          = 0
23267 sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO) = 99
23267 sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_FIFO) = 1
23267 writev(2, [{iov_base="/usr/local/sbin/tobiiusbserviced", iov_len=32}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="symbol lookup error", iov_len=19}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="/usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libtobii"..., iov_len=40}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="undefined symbol: pthread_create", iov_len=32}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
23267 exit_group(127)                   = ?
23267 +++ exited with 127 +++
```

Comment: Haven't thought about this before, but as far as I see it, there's no such thing as "the child's stdout"; the child has exact copies of its parent's open file descriptors, which includes stdout/err.

Comment: Maybe use `strace` to monitor what the child writes to `std{out,err}`?

Comment: Strace will most likely show a call to "dup2" in the child after the fork but before it does much else. This is typically how stdout and stderr is changed.

Comment: Can you try to explain this more clearly?  What does “It doesn't output the child's stdout or stderr” mean?  What result do you want?  Do you simply want to be able to wait until the child process terminates?  Do you want to see the output of the child process?  Where is that output going?  BTW, is the ```pgrep``` command successfully reporting the pid of the child process? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Good pointers, I've tried to.

Comment: `thecmd | cat` may at least block until the child process exits. The parent `thecmd` may exit, but as long as the child keeps its (inherited) stdout open, `cat` won't terminate by itself. Proof of concept: `ssh -f server 'sleep 10'` returns quickly, but `ssh -f server 'sleep 10' | cat` waits.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Good idea, but it probably won’t work in this case.  The `strace` output shows that the program closed file descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

- Your attempts to access `/proc/pid/fd/N`
  are probably futile.
- As long as the only access you have to the program is black-box,
  running `strace -f` may be the best you can do. 
  (Then search the `strace` output for `exit` and `write`.) 
  A similar option would be to try to run the program under a debugger. 
  If you want to automate this, try to identify clear requirements,
  do what you can, and then ask a new question if you get stuck.

  Probably the best solution would be to get white-box access;
  i.e., get the source code. 
  Using a reverse compiler, to generate source code from the binary,
  might be an option.
- Looking at the `strace` output you provided, we can see

  - The child process wrote “`23267`”
    to `/var/run/tobiiusb/tobiiusbservice.pid` using file descriptor 3. 
    This is, in fact, the PID of the child process.
  - It wrote “/usr/local/sbin/tobiiusbserviced: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/tobiiusb/libtobii…: undefined symbol: pthread_create\n”
    to file descriptor 2 using the `writev` system call. 
    The “…” in the above string is not literally three dots,
    but indicates text that has been truncated
    to prevent the output from being too verbose. 
    To see complete data,
    try passing the `--verbose=write` or `--verbose='/write*'` option to `strace`. 
    And/or `--write=all` (or `--write=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, if “`all`” doesn’t work).
  - The above error message didn’t appear anywhere
    because the program had previously closed file descriptors 0, 1 and 2.
  - As you suspected, the child process exited with status 127
    (using the `exit_group` system call).